# variable in definition

Tags: php

I'm loading an XML file into the page and want to get information from the URL parameter and put it in the url for the XML file that simplexml is laoding. is this possible? 
Here is the current code:

```
$gid = $_GET['gid']; 
$gach = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.com/GIDHERE/page.html?xml=1');
```

How can I put $gid where it says GIDHERE ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$gach = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.com/' . rawurlencode($gid) . '/page.html?xml=1');
```

You might also want to validate the input before using it, e.g.:

```
if (!preg_match('{^[1-9][0-9]*$}', $gid)) die;
```

If `$gid` is always an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gach = simplexml_load_file("http://xml.com/$gid/page.html?xml=1");
```

you have to use double quote, single quote disable variable parsing
and watch out for putting unchecked variable into url, you may end with exploits!
if gid is integer, just force it to be so by doing this

```
$gid = (int) $_GET['gid'];
```